# Django-allauth could not login existing user

Tags: django, django-allauth

I use Django 5 and django-allauth. Currently I do not use any advanced features of this library, the only reasons I use it:

1. It has a well-developed workflow with email opt-in feature
2. It can support both username and email based authentication out of the box.

Here is my settings, related to the library:

```py
# django-allauth specific settings for regular accounts not including the social authentication part.
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD="username_email"
ACCOUNT_CHANGE_EMAIL=True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET=False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION="mandatory"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL=True
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL="https"
ACCOUNT_MAX_EMAIL_ADDRESSES=2
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE=True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_PASSWORD_RESET=True
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER=True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED=False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE=False
# Our specific signup and login forms with special styling 
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'user_profile.forms.CustomSignupForm',
                 'login': 'user_profile.forms.CustomLoginForm'}
```

The only role of CustomLoginForm is to have customized css:

```py
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # The parent class does similar. The only reason we had to make custom loginform
        # to handle bootstrap css
        self.fields["login"].widget.attrs.update({"class": TEXT_INPUT_CLASS})
        if app_settings.AuthenticationMethod  == AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME:
            self.fields["login"].widget.attrs.update({"placeholder": "Felhasználónév",
                                                      "autocomplete": "username"})
        elif app_settings.AuthenticationMethod  == AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL:
            self.fields["login"].widget.attrs.update({"placeholder": "Email cím",
                                                      "autocomplete": "email"})
        else:
            self.fields["login"].widget.attrs.update({"placeholder": "Email cím / felhasználónév",
                                                      "autocomplete": "email"})

        self.fields["password"].widget.attrs.update({"class": TEXT_INPUT_CLASS,
                                                     "placeholder": "Add meg a jelszavad",
                                                     "autocomplete": "password"})
```

When I start my development server to see why I can not login with existing username and password, I used the Debug Toolbar to see SQLSs generated by the ORM:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
  FROM "auth_user"
 WHERE "auth_user"."username" = '''1@example.com'''
 LIMIT 21

SELECT "account_emailaddress"."id",
       "account_emailaddress"."user_id",
       "account_emailaddress"."email",
       "account_emailaddress"."verified",
       "account_emailaddress"."primary"
  FROM "account_emailaddress"
 WHERE "account_emailaddress"."email" LIKE '''1@example.com''' ESCAPE '\'

    
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
  FROM "auth_user"
 WHERE "auth_user"."id" IN ('4')

SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
       "auth_user"."is_superuser",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."first_name",
       "auth_user"."last_name",
       "auth_user"."email",
       "auth_user"."is_staff",
       "auth_user"."is_active",
       "auth_user"."date_joined"
  FROM "auth_user"
 WHERE "auth_user"."username" LIKE '''1@example.com''' ESCAPE '\'
 LIMIT 21
```

Since users can login by username or email, it's reasonable to see multiple queries. The one thing I do not understand is why string literals in the where conditions are surrounded by 4 additional quotation marks?

If I eliminate the redundant quotation marks, the query gives back the matchd user in Sqlite browser. If I do not remove the redundant quotation marks, it does not.

Whcih code puts the extra quotation marks and why? How can I fix this?